# Formatting output of Uninstall Programs - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to retrieve the Publisher, DisplayName, and DisplayVersion for each of the "uninstall" programs and put them in a file, with one line per product, with a comma between each entry as:

```
Publisher, DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

I need to maintain the entire content of each entry (i.e. not truncated, like `Format-Table` does).

I am placing each of the desired items into an array, to access later.

```
$Publisher = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select Publisher

$DisplayName = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select DisplayName

$DisplayVersion = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select DisplayVersion
```

So that I can loop through the entries, and write them out.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $DisplayName.Count; $i++)
{
    $MyOutput = ( ([string]::Concat($Publisher[$i].getValue, ",", $DisplayName[$i], ",", $DisplayVersion[$i]) | Out-String) ) 
    Add-Content D:\InstalledPrograms.txt $MyOutput
}
```

When I do this, my output has the Array Name in it as well like:

```
@{Publisher=Adobe Systems Incorporated},@{DisplayName=Adobe AIR},@{DisplayVersion=3.1.0.4880}
(i.e. @{ArrayName ArrayContent})
```

How can I get rid of the `@{ArrayName }` and only leave the content?

Answer (score 1):

You get this because you convert an object with a property to a string. Use ex. `$DisplayName[$i].DisplayName` in your `[string]::Concat` method to get the value from the property.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $DisplayName.Count; $i++)
{
    ([string]::Concat($Publisher[$i].Publisher, ",", $DisplayName[$i].DisplayName, ",", $DisplayVersion[$i].DisplayVersion) | Out-String) 
}
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Corporation,Microsoft Visual Studio Code,1.10.2
```

Or you could use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName` while collection the values. That will keep only the value. Atm. `Select-Object DisplayName` etc. are redundant since you still have to access the properties to get the value as shown above. Ex.

```
$Publisher = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select -ExpandProperty Publisher
```

However, I would rewrite this. You should get all the properties for an installation in a single object so you are 100% sure that the values belong to the same software. Try:

```
#Get all software in uninstall-key
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
#Remove empty lines
Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } |
#Arranging the properties in the order you want
Select-Object Publisher, DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
#Export to CSV
Export-Csv -Path "D:\InstalledPrograms.txt" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Ex. csv-output

```
"Publisher","DisplayName","DisplayVersion"
"Adobe Systems Incorporated","Adobe Flash Player 24 NPAPI","24.0.0.221"
"Tim Kosse","FileZilla Client 3.14.1","3.14.1"
"Microsoft Corporation","Microsoft Help Viewer 2.2","2.2.25123"
"mIRC Co. Ltd.","mIRC","7.43"
"Mozilla","Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1 (x86 en-US)","51.0.1"
"Mozilla","Mozilla Maintenance Service","51.0.1.6234"
"NVIDIA Corporation","NVIDIA Stereoscopic 3D Driver","7.17.13.7500"
"Valve Corporation","Steam","2.10.91.91"
"VideoLAN","VLC media player","2.2.4"
```

If the output file is a custom file, you can append like you did by replacing the `Export-CSV` with:

```
#Export to CSV and skip header
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
#Append to file.
Add-Content -Path "D:\InstalledPrograms.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks Frode. I need to process the data a bit before I write it (line by line), so I still need to copy it into a variable first. What you gave me is very helpful. Originally I had everything in one variable, but broke it apart when I was having problems getting things to be put into the file correctly. I get it now.